# How to test significance of pre-post difference scores on 8 measures (1 group)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, t-test, treatment-effect

I have a set of pre and post treatment scores on 8 measures. I'd like to test which of these show significant improvement after treatment. If I use within-subjects t tests it will mean carrying out 8 t tests, and risking type I error.

My textbooks all say that repeated subjects ANOVA is for more than two measures, but I only have 2 (pre & post). There is only one group - no control group or anything. What is the most appropriate test to use?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just perform a MANOVA?

(Post-Test Variables of Interest) = (Group-Related Variables of Interst).

Alternatively, you could perform a MANCOVA,
(Post-Test Variables of Interest) = 
(Pre-Test Variables of Interest AND Group-Related Variables of Interest).

Comment: Welcome to the site, @M.Buchler. Your post is being automatically flagged as low quality, because it is a little short, but I think it is a real answer. Would you mind expanding a little on the implicit argument behind this answer?